# ANOVA vs t-test: What is the advantage of running ANOVA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons

In statistics class, we are often taught that the advantage of ANOVA is that it can control for the type 1 error rate (the type 1 error rate will be inflated if we run many groupwise t-tests). The typical procedure for testing whether the means of several groups are different is:

> 1. ANOVA
> 2. If ANOVA produces significant results, run pairwise t-tests with Bonferroni adjustment

However, if that is the case, can I skip the ANOVA part altogether? With the Bonferroni adjustment, the type 1 error is under control. Then is there other benefits of using ANOVA?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/311164/176202